# How do I restore monitor resolution on my Dell XPS 15

Tags: intel-graphics, resolution

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my new Dell XPS 15  [This one here](http://configure.ap.dell.com/dellstore/config.aspx?oc=v520693au&model_id=xps-15-l521x&c=au&l=en&s=bsd&cs=aubsd1&).  It has the Ivy bridge processor with an Nvidia card.  I made the mistake of trying to install the nvidia proprietary driver.  On reboot I got 640x800 resolution :-(  So I apt-get remove --purge nvidia-current and it seems that the intel driver is now installed but I am stuck with 640x800.

Normally I would have booted using live cd (which has the correct resolution) and copy the xorg.conf from the live boot to the HDD.  But this doesn't seem to work with 12.04.

I have added the Modes "1920x1080" to the xorg.conf file but with no luck

I have tried manually editing and also deleting the ~/config/monitors.xml with no luck

I tried installing Bumblebee with no luck

Oddly, if I plug an external monitor in the HDMI port, I can set the resolution correctly on that monitor.

If I do xrandr in a terminal with the live cd it finds the correct resolutions, but when I try it from the install, it only returns 640x800 :-(

I would like to get my resolution back to native.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the xorg config file and reboot.

Use bumblebee afterwards.

Comment: You're a champion.  *facepalm* such a simple solution.  Thanks